# Making entire rows AND columns in an HTML table drag/droppable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a basic HTML table, with jQuery's sortable enabled to sort the table rows. [(Codepen for the table; code is below)](https://codepen.io/bkz44/pen/dyzbBMP)

My ultimate goal, is to be able to allow the user to drag/drop both rows and/or columns if they'd like. I am aware of the [connectWith option](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists) which can be passed to sortable, but it seems to make all individual td cells moveable - I only want this to apply to entire columns or entire rows (not the individual cells).

I've had a look at jQuery-ui's [sortable API documentation](https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/), but I am having a difficult time figuring out how this works; I am unsure if the basic sortable class can handle a scenario like this, or if I will need to construct some outside javascript to make this happen.

If I need to use my own javascript, that's not an issue - the problem is, I don't even know where to start (would it be something handled by event listeners?). I am not looking for someone to solve the problem for me - but curious if anyone knows if this sort of thing is possible with the basic sortable class, and if not (if I will need to construct my own js to do this), can you point me in the right direction on where to start, as I really am unsure.

Table HTML:

```
<table class="mytable">
  <caption>My Table</caption>
  <tr>
    <td id="corner"></td>
    <th scope="col">Col I</th>
    <th scope="col">Col .II</th>
    <th scope="col">Col .III</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="sortme">
    <th scope="row">Row I</th>
    <td>Open</td>
    <td>Open</td>
    <td>Open</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="sortme">
    <th scope="row">Row II</th>
    <td>Open</td>
    <td>Open</td>
    <td>Closed</td>
  </tr>
   <tr class="sortme">
    <th scope="row">Row III</th>
    <td>Open</td>
    <td>Open</td>
    <td>Closed</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

jquery:

```
$(function() {
    $( "tbody" )
        .sortable({items: "tr.sortme" });
});
```

EDIT: **I have solved this with [DataTables](https://datatables.net/manual/installation). It will do both row and column reordering simultaneous.** ([Working codepen](https://codepen.io/bkz44/pen/QWMWgZx).) The usage was incredibly simple. Read the [basic installation instructions](https://datatables.net/manual/installation) to find out what scripts you need, [download them (make sure to check 'ColReorder' and 'RowReorder' under the 'extensions' section)](https://datatables.net/download/)and then initialize your table as follows:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready( function () {
    $('#myTable').DataTable({
      searching: false,
      ordering:  false,
      rowReorder: true,
      colReorder: true,
    });
 });
</script>
```

It was that simple. Note, I have given the 'searching' and 'ordering' options as false because I don't want those features in the table in my situation - you do not need to supply those, and you might find those features useful.

**Something important to keep in mind**: The HTML posted above will **not** work with DataTables. There are 2 problems with it. (1) Using   tags within the rows (as row labels, or example where I'd written `<th scope="row">Row III</th>`) will not work. Instead, I turned those to  tags, then it worked. (2) Additionally, **your table must have a `<thead>` and `<tbody>` for DataTables to work** (See [this section of the install guide which mentions that.)](https://datatables.net/manual/installation#HTML).

Finally, I'd like to mention that I've found it useful to provide the following option when initializing DataTables:

```
rowReorder: {
    update: false
},
```

Apparently, the 'update' option can cause some undesirable behavior for certain tables. For my simple table, I noticed that unless I set this as false, I could only move the rows up and down by one row, no matter how far I dragged it. Setting it as false fixed that issue without causing any issues.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. there is no straight forward way to organize the columns. This is due to HTML Tables having Row definitions but not column definitions. So where it's easy to move rows and their child elements, it's harder to move columns.

Comment: You may first want to consider the DataTables library: https://datatables.net/ Both features you are looking for are availalbe to use already: https://datatables.net/extensions/colreorder/ If you do want to make your own with Sortable, this can be done.

Comment: That's sort of what I was thinking, and why I did not want to go down a rabbithole with sortable. I am not stuck on jquery sortable by any means - this library looks great, I will likely use this instead. Thanks a ton!

Comment: On a sidenote, in case this is useful to anyone in the future, I found this demo yesterday, which allows col and row re-ordering with jquery sortable, https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/twDXmS I have replicated it locally, but it seems to rely on some plugins which are now defunct. (The code for them is still accessible so I just downloaded it locally, but the homepage for them is a 404 and I don't believe it's maintained for many years.) DataTables lib seems like a better option (and won't need to rely on html tables for it.) But there's a demo that appears to work in case anyone is interested.

Comment: Also, in case anyone in the future ever tries out that demo I linked to - note that the file 'style.css' that he is using, is essential in making the column reordering work. (I kept trying it with everything but that, thinking it was just basic styling, but once I added that code to my example, it finally worked.)

Comment: I just wanted to say, I finally got DataTables up and running on my web page, and it works great. Both col reordering and row reordering can be done simultaneously. For anyone curious: This tells you how to install DataTables. https://datatables.net/manual/installation  .After importing the scripts, it was as simple as creating my HTML table, and then adding this as javascript: 

`$(document).ready( function () {$('#myTable').DataTable({searching: false, ordering:  false, rowReorder: true, colReorder: true, });} );`

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  function moveColumn(table, sourceIndex, targetIndex) {
    console.log("Move Col " + sourceIndex + " to " + targetIndex);
    var body = $("tbody", table);
    $("tr", body).each(function(i, row) {
      $("td", row).eq(sourceIndex).insertAfter($("td", row).eq(targetIndex - 1));
    });
  }

  $(".mytable > thead > tr").sortable({
    items: "> th.sortme",
    start: function(event, ui) {
      ui.item.data("source", ui.item.index());
    },
    update: function(event, ui) {
      moveColumn($(this).closest("table"), ui.item.data("source"), ui.item.index());
      $(".mytable > tbody").sortable("refresh");
    }
  });

  $(".mytable > tbody").sortable({
    items: "> tr.sortme"
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<table class="mytable">
  <caption>My Table</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td id="corner"></td>
      <th scope="col" class="sortme">Col I</th>
      <th scope="col" class="sortme">Col II</th>
      <th scope="col" class="sortme">Col III</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="sortme">
      <th scope="row">Row I</th>
      <td>Open</td>
      <td>Open</td>
      <td>Open</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sortme">
      <th scope="row">Row II</th>
      <td>Open</td>
      <td>Open</td>
      <td>Closed</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sortme">
      <th scope="row">Row III</th>
      <td>Open</td>
      <td>Open</td>
      <td>Closed</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This is a basic example. There are some pitfalls, like there is not a good placeholder for the Columns, where the Rows will have one.

Comment: This works beautifully! Thank you so much! I had been using the demo I mentioned in the comments above, but it was relying on a lot of external scripts, one of which was producing a bug I was unable to solve. This is simple, smooth, and works perfectly for my needs. Plus it makes 'sortable' make much more sense. It's just great! Thanks!

Comment: Oh wait, I have realized that this only shifts the column headers themselves, not the actual data cells. I will keep playing with it to see if I can get it to shift the entire column. Thank you for getting me started!

Comment: On a side note, it does appear to shift the columns sometimes (though the column headers always shift). I am unsure exactly under what scenario it is doing so, but I'm playing around with this. If I am able to get it working, will post a solution here. Either way, this seems like a much better approach than what I was doing initially